# Request data from object 2 that has the id of object 1 as attribute

Tags: android, kotlin

I have 2 data classes, Person and Dog.
Person has the following attributes:

personId, name, age, isFemale

```
data class Person (
  val personId: Int,
  val name: String,
  val age: Int,
  val isFemale: Boolean
)
```

Dog has the following attributes:

dogId, personId, name, age, isFemale

```
data class Dog (
  val dogId: Int,
  val personId: Int,
  val name: String,
  val age: Int,
  val isFemale: Boolean
)
```

I want to request all the dogs of a person, by using the id attribute. But I receive an error that dogs is not initialized and empty.

```
fun getTestPersons(): Array<Person>{
  return arrayOf(): Array<Person>(
   Person(1, "Harry", 35, false)
)
}

fun getTestDogs(): Array<Dog>{
  return arrayOf(
   Dog(1, 1, "Bert", 4, false), Dog(2, 1, "Linda", 6, true)
)
}
```

currentPerson has been initialized with for example the first one.

```
lateinit var dogs: MutableList<Dog>
for(dog in getTestDogs()){
if(dog.personId == currentPerson.personId){
  dogs.add(dog)
 }
}
```

Expected: A MutableList with all the dogs of a specific person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Collection.filter](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html) function is perfect for this

```
getTestDogs()
  .filter { dog -> dog.personId == currentPerson.personId }
  .toMutableList()
```